# Creating a function to put continuous data into discrete bins

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I am trying to create a function to put continuous data into discrete (user defined) bins for graphing and analysis. I have to do this for a number of variables that all require a different number of bins set at different intervals, and I'm finding myself writing very similar code over and over (see below), which is why I figured a function could be written. Additionally, I'm curious if there's a way to get a loop involved to simplify the code further.

**Code I'm writing again and again** (I've written similar code putting 1-10 ratings in bins)**:**

```
    decade <-
            ifelse(Year >= 1940 & Year < 1950, Decade <- "1940's",
            ifelse(Year >= 1950 & Year < 1960, Decade <- "1950's",
            ifelse(Year >= 1960 & Year < 1970, Decade <- "1960's",
            ifelse(Year >= 1970 & Year < 1980, Decade <- "1970's",
            ifelse(Year >= 2010 & Year < 2020, Decade <- "2010's",
            ifelse(Year >= 1980 & Year < 1990, Decade <- "1980's",
            ifelse(Year >= 1990 & Year < 2000, Decade <- "1990's",
            ifelse(Year >= 2000 & Year < 2010, Decade <- "2000's",
        NA))))))))
```

**My attempt at a function** (doesn't work)**:**

```
    bins <- function (variable, binName, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9=NULL, b10=NULL) {
        binname <- (
            ifelse(variable >= b1 & variable < b2, binName <- paste(b1, 's'),
            ifelse(variable >= b2 & variable < b3, binName <- paste(b2, 's'),
            ifelse(variable >= b3 & variable < b4, binName <- paste(b3, 's'),
            ifelse(variable >= b4 & variable < b5, binName <- paste(b4, 's'),
            ifelse(variable >= b5 & variable < b6, binName <- paste(b5, 's'),
            ifelse(variable >= b6 & variable < b7, binName <- paste(b6, 's'),
            ifelse(variable >= b7 & variable < b8, binName <- paste(b7, 's'),
            ifelse(variable >= b8 & variable < b9, binName <- paste(b8, 's'),
        NA)))))))))         }

    bins(Year, decade1, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `cut` with breaks. i.c .`cut(Year, breaks= c(-Inf,seq(1940, 2010, by=10), Inf))` and specify the `labels`

Comment: Noooooo. Use `findInterval` or `cut`. This is practically a FAQ on SO now. It's been asked so many times.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot - and apologies for this being a FAQ (I did search before... just couldn't find the right answer).

Cut works perfectly.

```
YearBins = paste(seq(1940, 2010, 10),"'s")
Decade <- cut(Year, seq(1940, 2020, 10), labels = YearBins)
#"Year" being the original continuous data, "Decade" being the new,bin'ed data.
```